# List binding in silverlight 4 (c#) with mvvm

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm

I have a list box bound to a collection, PlaylistTracks. PlaylistTracks contains a list id and a track id. All tracks are stored in another collection, Tracks. This collection has the track name.

Can I get the list box to display the track name from the collection its not bound to? Something like this:

```
<ListBox Name="PlayListTracksBox" 
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PlaylistTracks, Mode=TwoWay}" 
DisplayMemberPath="Tracks.Name" 
SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedListTrack, Mode=TwoWay}"></ListBox>
```

Comment: I think in a more correct MVVM implementation you would put the Track Name property on the ViewModels you are binding to in the list.

Comment: +1 for the above comment.  How will the listbox item know how to "look up" the track name?  You need to flatten the list you are binding to as kindohm said.

Answer (score 2):

I believe overriding `ToString()` for whatever class PlaylistTracks contains would be the fastest way to get what you want to work.  Inside of ToString you'd have to put whatever logic you need to look up the correct track, and return the name therefrom.

If you can get the track name into the top-level object in your ItemsSource, then the more "Silverlighty" way to get this to work is to provide an ItemTemplate and bind to whatever you want.  Something like:

```
    <ListBox>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Tracks.Name}"></TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```